How to get \cboxed with round corners?
I have a tex file of beamer class
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


\begin{equation} \label{main_eq4a}
\boxed{
d X_t = b(t, X_t, \textcolor{magenta}{\ell_t (X_t), \mu_t}) d t + \sqrt{2} d B_t .
}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{main_eq4a} is an SDE.

\end{frame}
\end{document}


Could you explain how to get the corners round? I tried \ovalbox{...} from package fancybox but to no avail.

Take a look at \tcboxmath from the theorems library of tcolorbox

What works very well for me and may work for you is embracing the math code within \tcboxmath{…your equation…}. You will need \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}, this package allows you to color your boxes. In my experience (with overleaf), tcolorbox has been extremely flexible (e.g. you can even put it inside tables and exponents).
I have modified your code accordingly:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


\begin{equation} \label{main_eq4a}
\tcboxmath{
d X_t = b(t, X_t, \textcolor{magenta}{\ell_t (X_t), \mu_t}) d t + \sqrt{2} d B_t .
}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{main_eq4a} is an SDE.

\end{frame}
\end{document}

If you are interested in more details and usage cases, here is the official documentation: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf


Do you know how to hide the black frame? I try \tcboxmath[frame hidden]{...} but to no avail.

Never mind, \tcboxmath[frame empty]{...} works for me.
